# How to compare the variation between two groups that are dividing participants into one of three categories?

Tags: anova

I have a group of approximately 130 participants. I am interested in evaluating the amount of food they consume per month. I have two different measures for evaluating them, mass and volume. I have split the participants into three tiers using the 1st and 3rd quartile each month. In the end I have two sets of data. Each has 12 rows of data and 3 columns. The rows represent the month the data was collected and the columns represent how many participants were in each tier that month. I would like to use the measure, volume or mass, that has the lowest variation of participants across tiers for the entire period.

How do I compare the variability of the two sets of data?

**Mass Table**

| Month | Tier 1 | Tier 2 | Tier 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 40 | 50 | 40 |
| February | 60 | 30 | 40 |
| March | 70 | 30 | 30 |
| April | 50 | 40 | 40 |
| May | 60 | 35 | 35 |
| June | 45 | 45 | 40 |
| July | 50 | 40 | 40 |
| August | 60 | 35 | 35 |
| September | 45 | 45 | 40 |
| October | 50 | 40 | 40 |
| November | 60 | 35 | 35 |
| December | 45 | 45 | 40 |

**Volume Table**

| Month | Tier 1 | Tier 2 | Tier 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 30 | 60 | 40 |
| February | 70 | 20 | 40 |
| March | 80 | 20 | 30 |
| April | 60 | 30 | 40 |
| May | 70 | 25 | 35 |
| June | 55 | 35 | 40 |
| July | 60 | 30 | 40 |
| August | 70 | 25 | 35 |
| September | 55 | 35 | 40 |
| October | 60 | 30 | 40 |
| November | 70 | 25 | 35 |
| December | 55 | 35 | 40 |